# Spring by enum to choose bean config properties

Tags: java, spring, config, configuration-files

My application has two running mode : SHORT, LONG. 
Each mode has different source folder which defined in config file. 
Assuming user will choose mode in run-time how can I set the chosen folder?

```
public enum Mode {
        SHORT,
        LONG
}

config.properties:

short.dir = short_test
full.dir = full_test 

@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:config/config.properties"})
public class runJob {
    @Value("${default.dir}")
    private String folder;

}
```

Thanks,Hila

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it's good idea to modify configurations in runtime based on user input. I suppose that you should collect all needed configurations, for example to `Map` and the get them by this runtime variable. E.G:

```
public enum Mode {
        SHORT,
        LONG
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config/config.properties")
public class AppConfig {
   @Value("${short.mode.dir}")
   private String shortModeDir;
   @Value("${long.mode.dir}")
   private String longModeDir;

   private volatile Map<Mode, String> configurationMap = new HashMap<>();

   @PostConstruct
   public void setUp() {
       configurationMap.put(Mode.SHORT, shortModeDir);
       configurationMap.put(Mode.LONG, longModeDir);
   }

   public String getDirectoryByMode(Mode mode) {
       return configurationMap.get(mode);
   }
}
```

You can use method `getDirectoryByMode` to get needed configuration.